# Improving DataTable performance (looping)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datatable, npoi

So I have a function to convert Datatable to NPOI Workbook.

Here's the code :

```
public static XSSFWorkbook DataTableToExcel(DataTable dt, string sheetName = "Sheet1")
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var excel = new XSSFWorkbook();
                var sheet = (XSSFSheet)excel.CreateSheet(sheetName);
                var col = sheet.CreateRow(0);

                //iterate columns
                for(int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
                {
                    col.CreateCell(x).SetCellValue(dt.Columns[x].ColumnName);
                }

                //iterate row
                for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++) //SLOW AS HELL
                {
                    var row = sheet.CreateRow(r + 1);

                    for (int c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
                    {
                        value = dt.Rows[r][c].ToString();
                        row.CreateCell(c).SetCellValue(value);
                    }
                }

                return excel;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

My problem is that the performance is horrible (10.000 rows took around 30 minutes) cause by the loop.

Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: Are you sure you need to *create* each cell? Typically just setting a cell's value is enough.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you give me the code example?

Comment: You have to figure out what exactly is degrading the performance. Is it the reading of the datatable, or is it the writing of the data in the excel workbook objects?

Comment: I can't because I never use it, I use EPPlus which is native to .NET and Excel. In VBA macros or EPPlus you only access a field by its address and set its value, eg "A1" etc. I'm not sure if NPOI has similar functionality, but EPPlus can load data from any DataTable or Collection with a simple `LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection` call.

Comment: @Maarten: The loop through each row in datatable is the main culprit

Comment: BTW how many columns do you have? A very wide table could cause delays but this kind of delay is far too much

Comment: @warheat1990 Have you done some performance measurements? Used a profiler?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Around 10-15 columns

Comment: Also, are you creating an XLSX or XLS table? XLSX is just compressed XML files, which makes writing them much easier. XLS is the old binary format with no official way to write it. Perhaps creating XLS files with NPOI is simply too slow

Comment: You can eliminate the continuous reading of `dt.Rows.Count` and `dt.Columns.Count` by storing the values of those in variable, and use that value in the `for (...; ...; ...)`.

Comment: @Maarten: I use the built-in `[Test]` project from Visual Studio.

Comment: @warheat1990 I suggest you use a profiler to actually see how much time is spent on individual lines of code. The `[Test]` project allows you to see how much time is spent on complete methods. Knowing which lines are taking up your CPU time are critical to your solution.

Comment: I can't exactly reproduce the delay - using this code with a test table of 30K rows with 15 columns, takes 5 seconds while EPPlus takes less than 1 sec . It's a lot slower but not catastrophically slow.